# ApacheBeam-Java: MongoDB Filters

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-beam, dataflow

I am new to the dataflow/Apchebeam. I am working on ingesting the data from MongoDB. MongoDB connection is working fine but I am not able to apply the filters. Throwing the following error.  I am not sure this is the right way to filter the data. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Error

**2021-06-07 10:37:34.615 CESTError message from worker: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.dataflow.dofns.MongodDbQueryFn cannot be cast to org.apache.beam.sdk.io.mongodb.AggregationQuery org.apache.beam.sdk.io.mongodb.MongoDbIO$BoundedMongoDbSource.split(MongoDbIO.java:522)**

**Code: MongoDbIO Connector:**

```
return  pipeline.apply(MongoDbIO.read()                        
.withUri("mongodb://".concat(databaseDetails.getDatabaseHostName()).concat(":").concat(databaseDetails.getPort()))
.withDatabase(databaseDetails.getDatabaseName())
.withCollection(objectDetails.getObjectName())
.withQueryFn(new MongodDbQueryFn("name","Mahesh")));
```

**QueryFn PTransform**

```
package com.test.dataflow.dofns;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction;
import org.bson.Document;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;

public class MongodDbQueryFn implements SerializableFunction<MongoCollection<Document>, MongoCursor<Document>> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String keyName;
    private String KeyValue;

    public MongodDbQueryFn(String keyName, String KeyValue) {

        this.keyName = keyName;
        this.KeyValue = KeyValue;

    }

    @Override
    public MongoCursor<Document> apply(MongoCollection<Document> input) {
        return input.find(com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq(keyName, KeyValue)).iterator();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is there any more to the stacktrace? Does it explain why it can't cast MongoDbQueryFn to an AggregationQuery? Because this looks to me like it should work. Maybe it's as simple as implementing an [AggregationQuery](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.27.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/mongodb/AggregationQuery.html) instead of SerializableFunction?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No much information from the log.                                                     Do you have any examples already for AggregationQuery?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `withQueryFn` doesn't explain this very well, but from reading through the code to MongoDbIO it seems that `MongoDbIO.Read` assumes that the `QueryFn` is set to either [`AggregationQuery`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.27.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/mongodb/AggregationQuery.html) or [`FindQuery`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.27.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/mongodb/FindQuery.html). The error you're getting is occurring because the code is checking if the queryFn is a `FindQuery`, getting false, and then assuming it's an `AggregationQuery` and attempting to cast it.

The best solution for you would be to use `FindQuery` to get the same behavior as the one you wrote, as follows:

```
.withQueryFn(FindQuery.create().withFilters(Filters.eq("name", "Mahesh"))));
```

Comment: As a note, I've submitted a [starter bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-12466) to the Apache Beam Jira to improve the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well, I was struggling with this issue since last week. I am new to apache beam and really feel difficult to understand and what to use when and not getting more examples from the internet at least for Java implementation.                                 Any suggestions, sharing reference links, or examples would be helpful to gain quick knowledge on it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am replying too late now, but, If you or anyone else still looking for solution to handle multiple filter criteria scenarios including with (AND/OR/etc).

The Filters.eq filter way of doing will create additional overhead(in-order to avoid recursive building multiple eq and noteq, etc cases).

My suggestion would be more in favor to convert the mongo.JSON string to Document
The good part is, mongo Document accepts json with comma(,) separator, hence the below couple of line of code can handle all the possible filter scenarios.

```
    String filterJson="{\n" +
            "     status: \"A\",\n" +
            "     $or: [ { qty: { $lt: 30 } }, { item: /^p/ } ]\n" +
            "}";

    Bson dc =BsonDocument.parse(filterJson);

    PCollection<Document> mongoVal = p.apply(MongoDbIO.read()
                    .withUri("mongodb://localhost:27017")
                    .withDatabase("test")
                    .withCollection("inventory_collection")
                    .withQueryFn(FindQuery.create().withFilters(dc)));
```